# Wireless MIDI piano keyboards

Tags: wireless

Are there any wireless MIDI keyboard controllers still being made?

Surprisingly from my googling it appears that there is only the the M-Audio MidAir 25 and MidAir 37, both of which are no longer being sold anywhere, not even ebay!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/is-there-a-wifi-midi-controller-keyboard?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Just did a google search and found several

http://www.dolphinmusic.co.uk/product/33587-cme-uf50-includes-free-usb-wireless-midi-adaptor.html

http://www.guitarcenter.com/CME-UF-50-49-Key-Master-Keyboard-MIDI-Controller-702722-i1323976.gc?source=4WWRWXGP&kpid=702722&cagpspn=pla

http://www.musiciansfriend.com/keyboards-midi/cme-uf-50-classic-midi-controller?src=3WWRWXGP

http://www.musiciansfriend.com/keyboards-midi/cme-uf-70-classic-midi-controller/h67906007000004?src=3WWRWXGP&kpid=mfH67906P.004&gclid=CKfcyuDo_7QCFUdxQgod7GMAEQ

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know of any particular devices with wireless midi built in, there are many many devices that could be plugged in to a midi keyboard and relay the midi signal wirelessly.  This is really the equivalent of a guitarist having a wireless belt (or strap) pack.